# Tixati tray icon is not displaying

Tags: system-tray

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, I have installed `tixati` torrent client but I cannot manage to display in the tray icon ( it is the default behavior)

Comment: refer [here](http://support.tixati.com/settings%20-%20user%20interface%20-%20behavior)

Comment: sorry maybe it is not clear in my question ... the issue is that ubuntu doesn't display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu 15.10**
So far the only solution was to install `indicator-systemtray-unity`.

Github Project page: https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity

there is an official ppa, so to install it just follow this instruction:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity
```

Once installed log out and log in.